# how to comparison with another attr not use subquery in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

there is two attr about workers.

name: worker's name, worth : worker's worth

i want to comparison worker's worth more than mike'worth

```
select w1.name
from worker w1, worker w2
where w1.worth>w2.name='mike'.worth ///???
```

i want to know how i write code in where phrase

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood it, but - if my name is Littlefoot and my worth is $0.01, what is result of such a comparison? Could you post some sample data and desired result?

Comment: that is my mistake. i want to result that worker's name who have more worth than mike have

Comment: Looks like you have to learn a basic syntac for SQL, because SQL operates with tables (sets of rows) and column values, not classes and their instances. There's no such thing as `string.property`, you have to filter table's columns by their value to restrict rows

Comment: `select w1.name from worker w1 join (select worth from worker where upper(name)='MIKE')x on w1.worth>x.worth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '`WHERE`' clause is used to filter records.
It is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified condition.
The comparison can be of similar data types only.
You can compare or put in condition for comparison of
`name` to `name`

`worth` to `worth`

but not`name`to`worth`.